# Selecting text in input and deleting not change input value (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an input and a button that reads the value and add it to the list.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-8">
        <input
           #sparePartsInput
           class="form-control"
           type="text"
           name="sparePart"
           maxlength="32"
           />
           {{sparePartsInput.value}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <button
            [disabled]="sparePartsInput.value == '' || sparePartsInput.value.trim() == ''"
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="addItemToSpareParts(sparePartsInput.value)>
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I set the button disabled when the value of the input is empty.

But when I select the value with `CTRL+A` and `delete`, its value seems not to empty. I need to click delete one more time and then it will be cleared.
How can I fix this stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[(ngModel)]="sparePartValue"`

Try like this:

**[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjsrbk?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-8">
        <input
           #sparePartsInput
           class="form-control"
           type="text"
           name="sparePart"
           maxlength="32"
           [(ngModel)]="sparePartValue"
           />
           {{sparePartsInput.value}}
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        <button
            [disabled]=" sparePartValue == null ||sparePartValue == ''"
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="addItemToSpareParts(sparePartsInput.value)">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Button
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```